# GeoTiffReader prevents deleteOnExit

Tags: java, geotools, geotiff

If I pass GeoTiffReader a File instance which has been marked as deleteOnExit() that file will not be deleted on exit.

```
File geotiffFile = Paths.get("geotools-test.tiff").toFile();
geotiffFile.deleteOnExit();
GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(geotiffFile);
reader.read(null);
```

To isolate the problem I tried a version without the GeoTiffReader which works as expected:

```
File geotiffFile = Paths.get("geotools-test.tiff").toFile();
geotiffFile.deleteOnExit();
Files.readAllBytes(geotiffFile.toPath());
```

I suspect GeoTiffReader isn't releasing the file handle at exit. Full code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader;

public class GeoTiffReaderLingeringHandles
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        main_working(args);
        // main_broken(args);
    }

    public static void main_working(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        File geotiffFile = Paths.get("geotools-test.tiff").toFile();
        geotiffFile.deleteOnExit();
    }

    public static void main_broken(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        File geotiffFile = Paths.get("geotools-test.tiff").toFile();
        geotiffFile.deleteOnExit();
        GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(geotiffFile);
        reader.read(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, I believe you need to dispose of the planarimage.  Using your code as an example,

```
public static void main_broken(String[] args)
    throws IOException
{
    File geotiffFile = Paths.get("geotools-test.tiff").toFile();
    geotiffFile.deleteOnExit();
    GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(geotiffFile);
    GridCoverage2D result = reader.read(null);
    PlanarImage planarImage = (PlanarImage) result.getRenderedImage();
    ImageUtilities.disposePlanarImageChain(planarImage);
}
```

This should delete your GeoTiffFile on exit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`dispose()`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/coverage/grid/io/AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.html#dispose--) of a GridCoverageReader so that it has a chance to release the underlying `inputStream` which would prevent a brain dead operating system deleting the file later.

Comment: Good shell of an answer but Justin L's is more complete. Windows is brain dead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you only have to dispose of the coverage reader